# Python: how to make a pie chart based on a confusion matrix, and export it into HTML file

Tags: python, data-visualization

As per title, my confusion matrix is created like this:

```
#!/home/pdc-labor/anaconda/bin/python

import csv
import argparse
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Creating confusion matrix.')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input path/to/file.csv', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-oh', '--output-html', help='Output path/to/confusion_matrix.html', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-oc', '--output-csv', help='Output path/to/confusion_matrix.csv', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

data = csv.reader(open(args.input, 'r'), delimiter=";", quotechar='|')
next(data)

true_data = []
pred_data = []

for row in data:
    if len(row) >= 2:
        true_data.append(row[0])
        pred_data.append(row[1])

true_data = [s.strip().split('_')[0] for s in true_data]
pred_data = [s.strip().split('=')[0] for s in pred_data]

y_true = pd.Series(true_data, name="Actual")
y_pred = pd.Series(pred_data, name="Predicted")
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_true, y_pred)
df_confusion.to_html(args.output_html)
df_confusion.to_csv(args.output_csv)
```

So at the end, it will create a `file.html` which will contain a table with the confusion matrix. In the same `file.html` I want to add a pie chart, with the values inside the confusion matrix. As far as I've seen, this can be done, with `Series.plot.pie`. The problem is that I don't understand how... The guys put some random data in their tutorial, but I don't understand what that data means.

P.S. it is not mandatory to use pandas. My ultimate goal is to have the same `file.html` to contain a confusion matrix, and a pie chart with the data from confusion matrix.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant way and also I am not sure as to what extent I am right or wrong but this is what I will be doing

```
import sklearn
y_true = pd.Series(true_data, name="Actual")
y_pred = pd.Series(pred_data, name="Predicted")

cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, sample_weight=None)
```

after this I would convert this array cm to list

```
list_1 = cm.tolist()
```

and then store it in dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_1, column = 'Confusion_Matrix', index=False)
```

and plot it to pie

```
 DataFrame.plot.pie(y='Confusion_Matrix')
```

Hope this solves your problems

Cheers!